# Enable specific email notifications and disable all other

Tags: magento2, email, wishlist, send-mail

Is any way to enable only two types of email notification from Magento 2.4.2 and disable all other email communication from Magento?

For example, I have to enable share wishlist and forgot password emails and stop all other email notifications like sales orders,customer registration etc.

Comment: You need to do the customization for this one, which email you want to stop.